# Why doesn't WCF service output change when I rebuild a referenced class library?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a very simple (new to this) RESTful WCF service that uses a referenced class library to query a database and then return the information to a browser.  If I modify the class library to change the contents of the data returned to the WCF service and rebuild, the old data is still returned to the browser.  I need to rebuild the class library AND the WCF service in order to have the browser display the new data.  I didn't expect this behavior. Why do I need to rebuild the WCF service if nothing has changed there?

I coding in C# in the SharpDevelop IDE. .NET 4.0

```
Browser --> WCF --> Class library --> Database
                                         |
Browser <-- WCF <-- Class library <-------
```

Thanks

Comment: Most likely the assemblies are not being refreshed into the WCF service directory, have you checked that the libraries in your WCF service directory are up to date after you build the class library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how the service is setup. If it is a web site type project, you should only need the newly recompiled reference DLL. However, if you are compiling the WCF service into a DLL, it too will need a complete recompile.

Comment: I don't yet understand .NET and my IDE well enough to corroborate this answer but it makes sense and is surely correct.  Thanks.